# MageTool - Does clear cache clear the sessions cache?

Tags: cache, full-page-cache, session

I am using the Mage Tool to clear my cache, and I am wondering, when I clear the cache using this tool, does it empty all the users shopping carts?

The tool can be found at :

https://github.com/alistairstead/MageTool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting your users sessions will empty their carts.
Or truncating `sales_flat_quote` tables.

Clearing the cache won't affect your users sessions/carts.

Comment: Raphael... that `*` meant something and it was in there with a purpose... there is more than 1 `sales_flat_quote` table...